# This Java class compiles smoothly but when I click on this when using my android phone as ADB. It says the device has stopped working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, android-studio

This is the class causing trouble because before writing this class, the program ran fine on the phone.
So I think the problem is with this class.
Please look in to find the problem.

JAVA CLASS:

```
package com.boston.ppp.boston;




import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Display; 
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

/**
* Created by ppp on 4/19/2015.
*/
public class TextPlay extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
 Button b;
ToggleButton tog;
EditText ed;
TextView tex;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);
    arnavbhai();
    tog.setOnClickListener(this);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void arnavbhai() {
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
    ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcommand);
    tex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresults);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            String check = ed.getText().toString();
            tex.setText(check);
            if (check.contentEquals("left")) {
                tex.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            }

            if (check.contentEquals("right")) {
                tex.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
            if (check.contentEquals("center")) {
                tex.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }
            if (check.contains("WTF")) {
                Random crazy = new Random();
                tex.setText("WTF");
                tex.setTextSize(crazy.nextInt(75));
                tex.setTextColor(Color.rgb(crazy.nextInt(265),crazy.nextInt(265),crazy.nextInt(265)));
                switch(crazy.nextInt(3))
                {
                    case 0:
                        tex.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tex.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tex.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                        break;
                }
            }
            else {
                tex.setText("invalid");
                tex.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tex.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.togglebutton:
            if (tog.isChecked()) {
                ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            } else {
                ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

}

**ERROR SHOWN** :

```
04-21 18:18:02.157    8024-8024/com.boston.ppp.boston W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41662d40)
04-21 18:18:02.161    8024-8024/com.boston.ppp.boston E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.boston.ppp.boston, PID: 8024
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.boston.ppp.boston/com.boston.ppp.boston.TextPlay}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.boston.ppp.boston.TextPlay.onCreate(TextPlay.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 18:20:23.527    8024-8024/com.boston.ppp.boston I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 8024 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Hi, is the buttons (either `togglebutton` or `button1`) exists in your layout file? would be great if you can show us the layout file.

Comment: <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/bresults" />
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="80"
   android:checked="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/togglebutton"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, based on your comment. I think the problems is because of this

**Layout**

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="20" 
    android:text="New Button" 
    android:id="@+id/bresults" 
/> 
<ToggleButton 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="80" 
    android:checked="true" 
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" 
    android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
/>
```

**Code**

```
Button b;
ToggleButton tog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    arnavbhai();
    tog.setOnClickListener(this); 
    b.setOnClickListener(this);   <-- seems this part is throwing NPE
}

private void arnavbhai() {
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); <-- shouldn't it be R.id.bresults ?
    tog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the line 32.

You have to find your UI elements and define them in your code. Something like:

```
b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_BUTTON);
tog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ID);
```

Then, you can call the listenners.

Comment: Sir,  
I have initialised tog and b in the arnavbhai() method below and have called this method prior to using it.

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing `tog` and `b` without initialization which is causing a `NPE`. add

```
tog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.idOfTOG);
b = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.idOfButton);
```

in `onCreate` before calling `setOnClickListener`

Comment: I have initialised tog and b in the arnavbhai() method below and had called this method prior to using it.                                                           private void arnavbhai() {
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
    ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcommand);
    tex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvresults);

}

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException being thrown from TextPlay.onCreate(), line 32.  It's right there in the stack trace.

Now, you can either
* Attach a debugger and step through the method, looking for null references, or
* Trace the set-up of your class and see where the null reference could be coming from

Comment: That's hardly necessary - one can simply look at line 32 of the program and see what is referenced there.